# In fragment, unable to get a reference to the hosting activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewpagerindicator

I have a fragment hosted by a ViewPager

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

DatabaseHelper db;
String TAG = "FragmentOne";
DisplayActivity displayActivity;
....
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    displayActivity = new DisplayActivity();
    initView();
}
    Button delete = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.dont);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayActivity.removeCurrentFragment(count-1);


        }
    });
```

My goal is to remove this current fragment from the ViewPager. However, through the debugger I found that displayActivity is null.

How do I get a reference of displayActivity?

```
public class DisplayActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
String TAG = "DisplayActivity";


public void removeCurrentFragment(int position){
    pagerAdapter.fragmentArrayList.remove(position);
    pagerAdapter.notifyChangeInPosition(1);
    pagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.e(TAG, "in removeCurrentFragment");
}
```

I tried using displayActivity = new DisplayActivity();
But doesn't seem to work.

This is the error

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void .DisplayActivity.removeCurrentFragment(int)' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getActivity()` with a cast to `DisplayActivity`.

```
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    displayActivity = (DisplayActivity) getActivity();
    initView();
}
```